# sending data to firebase with react/redux

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux

How do i get the submit function to work in this component? Props is undefined so should i make a state?
I feel like i have misunderstood something really basic, it seems harder with Firebase than without.

The action is

```
export function savePost(post) {
  return dispatch => database.push(post)
}
```

```html
class AddPost extends Component {
  
  onSubmit(values) {
    this.props.savePost(values)
    .then(this.props.dispatch());
  }
 
  render() {
    
    return (
      <div className="container">
       <form >
       <input type="text" name="title"/>
       <input type="text" name="body"/>
       <button type="submit">Post</button>
       </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({

  //

 });
export default connect(mapDispatchToProps, {savePost})(AddPost)
```

Answer (score 0):

The connect method should accept `mapSateToProps` then `mapDispatchToProps`.

So if you are trying to dispatch savePost.

Try:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  savePost: dispatch(savePost())
});

export default connect(undefined, mapDispatchToProps)(AddPost);
```

Comment: i feel like the submit could be redone somehow because it doesn't work. Props is undefined.

Comment: Try ` <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>` and then follow the example here: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components